# Windows fails to mount the non-english mount points

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

```
$dofflinescript =@"
       select disk 7
        attributes disk clear readonly
        online disk
        assign mount='C:DATABASES\データベースが\DATA5'
        format unit=64K quick 
    "@
    $dofflinescript | diskpart
```

I am using above PowerShell script to assign a mount-point to the disks

But Powershell is failing with error

```
DiskPart has encountered an error: The parameter is incorrect
```

The above error is happening for the **assign mount=** statement

How can I solve this?

Comment: diskpart is not a Powershell cmdlet. So it cannot use pipeline input. As far as I know you could provide a script file with the parameter /s like this `diskpart /s scriptfile.txt`.

Comment: @Olaf Still that dint work,Same issue

Comment: what happens when you type all these commands you have in your script file at the diskpart prompt?    BTW: it's actually not a Powershell issue. You should remove the Powershell tags.